# Run mongodb from meteor

Tags: mongodb

I am getting the following error when I run MongoDB:

```
C:\Users\wangzd-d\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.11.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:313
                                           throw(ex);
                                           ^

MongoError: user is not allowed to do action [listIndexes] on [test.users]
     at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wangzd-d\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\3.8.1\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:451:61)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
W20201117-10:32:47.706(8)? (STDERR)     at processMessage (C:\Users\wangzd-d\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\3.8.1\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:452:10)
     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wangzd-d\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\npm-mongo\3.8.1\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:621:15)
     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
     at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
     at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
   ok: 0,
   code: 8000,
   codeName: 'AtlasError'
 }
```

Any idea why this is happening? U

Comment: this has no meaning pliz turn it into data

Comment: "MongoError: user is not allowed to do action [listIndexes] on [test.users]" - have you configured any role for the user in your admin db?